# Understanding language mixing

Tags: javascript, ruby, visualization

Specifically speaking, I have a school project in Ruby that creates imaginary relationships between nodes of words, like a graph.

It has a class named `interactive.rb` that is like an interactive shell. It reads my commands and outputs to the console. e.g. the command `load <path>` would load data into my graph object and output something like `load success!`. It also has other features for looking up the relation between nodes and outputting it to the console. I want to use [this](http://p5js.org) to make a cool visual frontend that displays the graph, but it's unfortunately in JavaScript. Is there a way I can mix the languages up? Someway of utilizing the data-structure I already created and parse it into Javascript?

If not, can someone point me in the right direction to visualizations in Ruby? I'm not interested in a GUI, just something to display what the graph looks like.

Comment: There's some ruby to JS transpilers that turn ruby code into JS code. Use at own precaution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to communicate between a ruby layer and a JS frontend is through JSON. [Here](http://flori.github.io/json/) you can find a gem for JSON in ruby.

Anyway if you need graph representation I really suggest you to take a look into Graphviz that I think in my opinion is one of the most cool tool available right now for this kind of task. Take a look on the official website [here](http://www.graphviz.org/) and look also for ruby integrations for example on github like [this](https://github.com/glejeune/Ruby-Graphviz).